# soundPool or Mediaplayer for short sound and help needed

Tags: android, audio

i have created a simple app that has few buttons in a screen. one of the button is called a soundButton, where, when the user press it, an audio file will be played. (e.g. a simple word like "apple"). i have around 100 of those similar screens, and when i play the sound for the first few times, i can hear the sound, and after a while, i can no longer hear them no matter which screen i go to (even the previous screen which can be heard no longer plays the sound) this is my coding, for reference :

```
package com.example.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class EngApple extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eng_apple);

        ImageButton soundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound);
        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.apple);


        soundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mp1.start();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

It is a flash card app where the sound is very short. i read that the method that needs to be used to play short sounds is by using soundPool. and so i have changed my code but in vain. (sounds not playing) can anyone help me please? thank you

Comment: Are you saying you have 100 Activities?

Comment: You are passing a "drawable" to the `MediaPlayer.create`? Is this a typo - or are you just overloading your `res\drawable` directory to include sound files?  I thought sound files were supposed to go in `res\raw`, but it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, the LogCat dump of what you see on the screen would be helpful. MediaPlayer has a lot of logging...

Comment: Mike : yes i am having around 100 of them. 
selbie : i didnt know u have to put it in raw. should i try it? and later i will run it again and post the LogCat dump. thanks

Comment: my logcat error09-01 18:06:19.740: E/MediaPlayer(821): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually do have 100+ activities following the pattern above, it means every time you start a new Activity screen, you are instantiating an instance of a MediaPlayer with the sound *already loaded*.  I suspect something just gives out by having that many MediaPlayer instances around at once. Given that your sounds are all in resources, you can defer the `.create` call to immediately before the `.start()` call.

Consider having a singleton class that manages exactly one instance of MediaPlayer.  Something like the following:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MediaPlayerWrapper
{
    static MediaPlayer _player;

    public static void play(Context context, int id)
    {
        stop();
        _player = MediaPlayer.create(context, id);
        _player.start();
    }

    public static void stop()
    {
        if (_player != null)
        {
            _player.reset();
            _player.release();
            _player = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then your onCreate method just becomes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eng_apple);

    soundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayerWrapper.play(EngApple.this, R.drawable.apple);
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually, i am still not sure what do u mean, where do i need to place this code? i am sorry i am new to android (started around 10 months ago) . by the way, i saw that for short sounds, soundpool is a better alternative. how do i use it?

Comment: I updated the answer and fixed some typos in both code samples. Create a new file called MediaPlayerWrapper.java and copy the above class definition into it. Add your `package` declaration at the top of this file.  Then modify your onClick listeners to be similar to the new modification I made above.

Comment: thanks! i hope it will work now! the only problem is that whenever i play the sound after the 20th activity or so, the sound is no longer heard.. i have to restart my app to hear it again. the error message shows that "MediaPlayer(9682): start called in state 0". any idea how to repair it? thanks.

Comment: Dear selbie,
THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your help :) I appreciate your help very much :D now my app works perfectly without any bugs! thank you once again for helping me :D